# How to stop streaming in the publish method of Wowza server

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, video-streaming, wowza

I need to stop publishing the stream in the `publish()` method and send the client a message such as "This name is incorrect, choose another."

I've looked at `sendClientOnErrorStatus()` but haven't found any examples showing how to handle it on the client side.

Also, can anyone explain what the `sendResult(..)` method does?

Comment: Mostly grammatical changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendClientOnErrorStatus()` and `sendResult()` only work in a **Flash** context.

**sendClientOnErrorStatus()**

On the Wowza server you can override the `publish` and `releaseStream` (for streams being published) methods and do something like:

`sendClientOnStatusError(client, "NetStream.Publish.Denied", "Stream name is invalid: " + streamName);`

On a Flash client using **ActionScript** you would add a NetStatusEvent listener:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
       switch (event.info.code) {
            // do something with the event.info
       }
}
```

**sendResult()**

This is used to send the result for a `NetConnection.call` which calls a custom method on the Wowza server.

Example:

Wowza server:

```
public void someMethod(IClient client, RequestFunction function,
            AMFDataList params) {
{
        sendResult(client, params, "response");
}
```

Client:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.call("someMethod",new Responder(function(data:String):void {
          trace(data);
       })
);
```

Source: [AS3 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)

Comment: Yep, it is what I need. Do You know some method to send message to the iOS or android client?

Comment: `publish()` is the server implementation of `NetStream.publish` and it works just for RTMP publishing (incoming connections to Wowza). What are you trying to do exactly? If you want something similar to `sendClientOnStatusError()` on a HTTP connection you could redirect to an error page or add some custom HTTP headers (if you have your own player).

Comment: As example: I have many files on the wowza server - for VOD. And I want to add one file. But first I wanna check is file with the same name exist and if yes - stop publishing and send some message to iOS or android client.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you since VOD files are not published. They're just files on the server (or network share/web server for Edge VOD).

Comment: Yes, just a file. It is not really important